# Confusion with global funtion

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I have written a code in ROS using python. So what my code does is something simple and calls a function 'callback'. My problem is with the callback function so this ends up as a problem in python.

When I define 'global var' inside the callback function and then define its type(var=Twist()) inside the callback function(i.e the 2nd and 3rd line of code are inside the callback function), I get an error as 'var is not defined'.
 Similarly for the case when I define 'global var' outside the callback function and then define its type(var=Twist()) inside callback. But I have seen examples where global variables are defined inside the function. 
Here is relevant part of my code.

```
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
    global var
    var=Twist()
    def callback(msg):

    v=msg.ranges
    if v[360]<1:
        var.angular.z=0.5
        var.linear.x=0
    else:
        if v[719]<1:
            var.angular.z=-0.3
            var.linear.x=0
        elif v[0]<1:
            var.angular.z=0.5
            var.linear.x=0
        else:
            var.linear.x=1
            var.angular.z=0
    print('var value is',var)



rate = rospy.Rate(2)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
sub = rospy.Subscriber('/kobuki/laser/scan',LaserScan , callback)
pub.publish(var)
```

Comment: There seems to be an indentation problem after `def callback(msg):`.  Also, the `global var` statement needs to go inside your `callback` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `global` keyword, the definition of the variable needs to be global (outside of the scope of the `callback()` function) AND the `global` needs to be inside the scope. [See example #3 here.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword#rules-global)